# I want to know how to check a hyperlink text and the link exists in an URL or not using c#

Tags: c#, hyperlink, screen-scraping

I want to create a tool that would help me to check whether a link and its text exists in a webpage or not using c#...Also want to know if the link is dofollow or nofollow. Example here is a link of a wiki site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page

You can see a lot of link text in the article body like
Arts,History etc .I want to check the if "Arts" link text exists or not with the correct hyperlink(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Arts) also if it is nofollow or dofollow. I am going to create a tool so please help me.

The main idea of the project is to monitor the link text and its link in an article online ,whether or not if it exists or deleted by someone.Also to know if it is dofollow or nofollow.

Comment: This seems like your just trying to drive traffic to your blog.  Cann't you add examples to your Question?

Comment: Hi is the example good enuf ?

Comment: @jradich1234 can you help me in this ?

Comment: Does the Webpage you're looking to read require you to login?

Comment: no its just an article page that can be viewed by anyone.I want to find out whether my link text and the link is existing or not......Thanks mate.Looking forward for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by nofollow or dofollow, but here is a quick code sample to iterate through the links on a web page.  This should be a good starting point to get you going.  If you're looking for something a little more robust you can look in to the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  It's a bit more complicated to use but you get the DOM view of the web page.

Since this is using the `WebBrowser` control insure to include the `System.Windows.Forms` reference.  If you must use a project type that does not allow for Forms object, this can be done with a `WebClient` or `WebRequest`, but both of those take a bit more effort to get working.

```
static void CheckLink() {
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

    wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
    //Pass FireFox as user agnent to prevent getting Mobile site
    wb.Navigate("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page",null ,null,"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0");
}

static void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    String html = wb.DocumentText;

    //find BODY tag
    int BodyPosition = html.ToUpper().IndexOf("<BODY");

    int Position = html.ToUpper().IndexOf("<A HREF", BodyPosition);
    while (Position  > -1) {

        int BeginUrlPosition = html.IndexOf("\"", Position);
        int EndUrlPosition = html.IndexOf("\"", BeginUrlPosition + 1);
        String link = html.Substring(BeginUrlPosition+1, EndUrlPosition - BeginUrlPosition -1);

        //Do Somthing with found link

        //Look for next Link
        Position = html.ToUpper().IndexOf("<A HREF", EndUrlPosition);
    }
}
```